# Jobs - that "attach resume" field?

Tags: support, stack-overflow-jobs

Here's something that just occurred to me, to which there needs to be a really definitive answer!

.

[image]

.

Say it's **Monday**, and I click to apply to nice company A.

In that slot, I attach my file A.pdf. (I write a short personalized note to A under "Introduce yourself".

It's **Tuesday**, and I click to apply to nice company B.

In that slot, I attach a different file B.pdf. (I write a different short personalized note to B under "Introduce yourself".)

Now it's **Wednesday**, and a nice person at company A gets the application (whether they use a web interface or what, I do not know).

On **Thursday**, a nice person at company B gets the application.

## Is it absolutely the case .....................

That company A will get (and will only get) pdf A ?

and company B will get (and will only get) pdf B ?

?????????

---

*Please note that* when I return on Tuesday (part B above),

in fact the earlier "A.pdf" is ***indeed populating that interface element by default***.

That strikes me as a somewhat unsafe and/or unclear idea, but no matter about that.  I just want to know definitively how this works! Thx

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, Company A will get A.pdf (and only A.pdf) and Company B will get B.pdf (and only B.pdf)

Comment: HEH love the edit there man  :)

Comment: I could see the follow up coming ;)

Comment: hey thanks for the definitive answer from inside the code, programmer dude!  good one